# What is the meaning of changing char pointer to int pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char, integer, hex

I have the following code from previous exam in c:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char s[] = "123";
    int* a = (int*) s;
    printf(("%x"),*a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is: `333231`

My question is why? how does changing the pointer effect it?

Comment: The [ASCII characters](http://www.asciitable.com/) `123` are represented by the hex values `31`(1) `32`(2) `33`(3). Converting their type to `int` by changing the pointer type returns the values, not the characters.

Comment: Put a break point before the printf statement and look at the bytes stored in `s`. You should see four bytes, representing the ascii values for each of the digits, with a `\0` (null) byte at the end. Casting causes printf to treat those for bytes as if they are a integer, not four individual code points.

Comment: @DakotaMethvin thank you, I understand now, but why it printed 33 32 31 and not 31 32 33 ?

Comment: @none because your PC is little-endian

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to declare a separate variable. This would do:

```
printf(("%x"),(int*)s);
```

The pointer type dictates how the pointee is interpreted when the pointer is dereferenced.

Comment: but why it is printed in reversed order?

Comment: @none Because of endianess https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: thank you, now it is very clear that happening.